# OPAL-Regarding Finding Calledges of methods defined in Abstract Class using CHA algorithm

Tags: opal-framework

Here is a question related to the algorithm of constructing the call graph for Java bytecode using CHA.

As there is no concrete method implementation for methods in abstract classes, adding a call edge to such methods might be a bit misleading. 
take `junit-4.12.jar` for instance. `runFailed` has been defined in `junit.runner.BaseTestRunner` which is an abstract class. Besides, there are calls to `runFailed` in method `getTest` which also defined in `junit.runner.BaseTestRunner`

While in "Assumption Hierarchy for a CHA Call Graph Construction Algorithm"(Jason&Atanas), it is said that

> "given a call site x.m(), where the declared type of x is C, the
>   possible runtime type of x must be a non-abstract subtype of C."

As far as i'm considered, without add a call edge(Calledge1) from `junit.runner.BaseTestRunner getTest` to `junit.runner.BaseTestRunner runFailed`, it is more reasonable to add a call edge(Calledge2) from `junit.runner.BaseTestRunner getTest` to `junit/textui/TestRunner runFailed` as TestRunner extends BaseTestRunner.

While after running test code to get the result of CallGraph.calledByStatistics(), only Calledge1 has been found. Calledge2 is missing.

Is there anybody can do me a favor to confirm this?
Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Jiang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found OPAL offers two views of call graph. The second one won't add a "library-call" edge into call edge.

In CallGraph.calledByStatistics()

The binding is between Callsite (PC) to caller.method
for example: between “INVOKEVIRTUAL(junit.runner.BaseTestRunner{ void runFailed(java.lang.String) })” and 
junit/runner/BaseTestRunner.public junit.framework.Test getTest(java.lang.String)

In CallGraph.callsStatistics()

The binding is between subtype.method to caller.method
for example: 
between "junit/textui/TestRunner.protected void runFailed(java.lang.String)”  and “junit/runner/BaseTestRunner.public junit.framework.Test getTest(java.lang.String)”